# stochastic exponential of continuous local martingale is local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

Consider a  continuous local martingale $M$ and the stochastic exponential $Z(t)= \exp\{M(t) - 0.5 \langle M \rangle(t)\}$, where $\langle M \rangle(t)$ is the quadratic variation of $M$. Using Ito's formula one can show:

$$dZ(t)=Z(t)dM(t)$$ meaning: $$Z(t)= Z(0)+ \int_0^t Z(s) dM(s)$$

How can one verify that $Z_t$ is  local martingale? In general integrals w.r.t. local martingales are local martingales if $Z_s$ is predictable. I cannot see why this is the case here?

Comment: $Z$ is adapted and path-continuous. Does that help?

Comment: That means Z is left-continuous and adapted. Hence measurable w.r.t. the predictable sigma-field. But do I have this sigma-field?

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Is this kind of resoning ok?

Comment: Yes, $Z$ is predictable.